# What would have happened if the Night King were stabbed by dragonglass?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In GoT S8E3, we witnessed how

> dragon fire

does not cause any harm to the Night King but

> Valyrian steel can kill him.

Could a dragonglass dagger have killed him?

Comment: It's explained in Inside The Episode with D&D. Dragonglass wouldn't work on him. Valyrian steel only would work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [We Do Not <s>Sow</s> Know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd0V5.jpg)

In the Inside the Episode for the episode David Benioff says the following.

> **David:** We knew it had to be Valyrian steel to the exact spot where the Child of the Forest put the dragonglass blade to create the Night King, and he's uncreated by the Valyrian steel.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 3, "The Long Night" - Inside the Episode</sub>

However, I think the wording is unclear to if he means they had to as in they wanted it to be Valyrian steel or had to as had to in universe. As in it's not entirely clear if he's talking from a design standpoint or in universe. I'm inclined to believe it's the former though and that only Valyrian steel can kill the Night King.

Although, if my viewing of the scene is correct, David is wrong in one of the things he says here as Arya actually stabs the Night King in the belly rather than the heart as Leaf did when she created him. So something either got lost in translation with the filming and editing, I'm not seeing it right or David is mistaken. Compare the image of her stab on a straight line of armour to the full image of the Night King and that the straight line of the armour is only on the belly.

[image: Arya stabs the Night King] [image: The Night King walks away from the dragon fire]
<sub><sup>*Click the images to enlarge them.*</sup></sub>

This would then throw his whole statement into unclear waters so we can't assume that only Valyrian steel would kill him. However, in the zoomed out shot it looks like she stabs him in the belly so there appears to be some editing/filming inconsistencies.

[image: The Night King is killed]
<sub><sup>*Click the image to enlarge.*</sup></sub>

We do now that dragonglass can kill the White Walkers as we see Sam kill one with a dragonglass dagger. However, the Night King is something more and so might require something more to be killed.

Comment: Sorry for the poor quality images, trying to get some better ones.

Comment: we probably have to [wait for the Blu-Ray](https://techcrunch.com/2019/04/29/why-did-last-nights-game-of-thrones-look-so-bad-here-comes-the-science/) to get better images.

Answer (score -2):

If we assume that the Night King is similar to the White Walkers, he would be vulnerable to dragonglass. This assumption is likely given what we have seen of the White Walkers and Mr Night King himself. In appearance, origin, resistance to fire and other weapons, weakness to Valyrian steel, they are all very similar.

In one of the earlier seasons, during the ranging beyond the wall, we can see Sam kill an Other with a dragonglass dagger. This shows that White Walkers are weak to them. The Night King then would also be weak to them if the assumption above is true.

Comment: The NK has to be stabbed where the dragon glass had been pressed against his heart, would more dragonglass have penetrated that spot? I don’t think so.

Comment: @Edlothiad he had to be stabbed in a specific spot? Must've missed that part. In S8E3 he appears to die from a stab in the belly.

Comment: Not in the belly, it's covered in the "Game Revealed" on youtube